# Residues of $ \frac{z^4}{1+z^6} $

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I am trying to compute all 6 the residues of $ \frac{z^4}{1+z^6} $. I tried the straightforward way first of finding all the points where the denominator is 0 etc but it became way too complicated. Any ideas?

Comment: the denominator is zero when $z$ is a sixth root of $-1$

Comment: I know, I found all these points, but finding the residues based on that using the methods I tried was too complicated.

Comment: Have you tried "If $g$ has a simple zero at $z_0$, then $\operatorname{Res}\bigl( \frac{f}{g}; z_0\bigr) = \frac{f(z_0)}{g'(z_0)}$"? (Where of course $f$ and $g$ are supposed to be holomorphic at $z_0$.)

Comment: Oh jesus I just now realized the zeros are all simple! For some reason I had convinced myself they were all of order 6 and I couldn't shake it off... This is what happens when you've been solving complex analysis for 6 hours straight... Thanks for helping point me to the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a$ be a pole of $f(z)=z^4/(z^6+1)$. Then $a^6=-1$. Also $a$ is a simple pole.
The residue is thus
$$\lim_{z\to a}(z-a)f(z)=\lim_{z\to a}\frac{z^4(z-a)}{z^6-a^6}
=\frac{a^4}{\lim_{z\to a}\frac{z^6-a^6}{z-a}}.$$
But
$$\lim_{z\to a}\frac{z^6-a^6}{z-a}=g'(a)$$
when $g(z)=z^6$ etc.

Comment: Hmmm alright, but the sum of all the residues is then 0, right? The reason this is concerning to me is that I am using it to calculate an integral that shouldn't be 0.

Comment: Sorry, I'm dumb, I was using the wrong formula, nothing concerning, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$z^6 + 1$ has roots $e^{\frac {(2k+1)\pi }{6}i}$

We might factor the denominator like this.

$(z-e^{\frac {\pi}{6} i})(z^5 + z^4e^{\frac {\pi}{6}i} + z^3e^{\frac {2\pi}{6}i} + z^2e^{\frac {3\pi}{6}i} + ze^{\frac {4\pi}{6}i} + e^{\frac {5\pi}{6}i})$

$\lim_\limits{z\to  e^{\frac {\pi}{6}i}} \frac {z^4}{z^6+1} (z-e^{\frac {\pi}{6}i}) = \lim_\limits{z\to  e^{\frac {\pi}{6}i}} \frac {z^4}{(z^5 + z^4e^{\frac {\pi}{6}i} + z^3e^{\frac {2\pi}{6}i} + z^2e^{\frac {3\pi}{6}i} + ze^{\frac {4\pi}{6}i} + e^{\frac {5\pi}{6}i})}$

As $z$ approaches $e^{\frac {pi}{6} i},$ each term in the denominator approaches $e^{\frac {5\pi}{6}i}$

$\lim_\limits{z\to  e^{\frac {\pi}{6}i}} \frac {z^4}{z^6+1} (z-e^{\frac {\pi}{6}i})=\frac {e^{\frac {4\pi}{6} i}}{6e^{\frac {5\pi}{6}i}} = \frac {e^{-\frac {\pi}{6}i}}{6}$

Now that we have one residue, the rest get easier.  To find the residue at $e^{\frac {3\pi}{6}i}$ we can quickly jump through the algebra above to

$\lim_\limits{z\to  e^{\frac {3\pi}{6}i}} \frac {z^4}{z^6+1} (z-e^{\frac {3\pi}{6}i}) = \frac {e^{\frac {12\pi}{6}i}}{6e^{\frac {15\pi}{6} i}} = \frac {e^{-\frac {3\pi}{6}i}}{6}$

And the pattern becomes more obvious.  The rest of the residues are:

$\frac {e^{-\frac {5\pi}{6}i}}{6}, \frac {e^{-\frac {7\pi}{6}i}}{6},\frac {e^{-\frac {9\pi}{6}i}}{6}, \frac {e^{-\frac {11\pi}{6}i}}{6}$

Comment: That is what I tried to do at first but there is a simpler way, which is to simply use the formula someone mentioned in the comments beneath my post.

Comment: It is a worthwhile exercise.  Once you have done it once or twice, you start to see the patterns.